# 3 table relationship with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I'm new to Entity Framework relationship and having trouble with 3 tables though I worked out for 2 tables. Here is my problem

I have following models:

```
public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
        this.Leaves = new HashSet<Leave>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string middle_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string facebook { get; set; }
    public string contact_number { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string admin { get; set; }
    public string college { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime createdat { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime updatedat { get; set; }
    public string descripton { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Leave> Leaves { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class StudentCourse
{
    public StudentCourse()
    {
        this.Fees1 = new HashSet<Fee>();
        this.Issues = new HashSet<Issue>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public int student_id { get; set; }
    public int course_id { get; set; }
    public int fees { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime join_date { get; set; }
    public string admin { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime createdat { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime updatedat { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Fee> Fees1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
        this.CourseContents = new HashSet<CourseContent>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string course_name { get; set; }
    public int course_fees { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public string admin { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime createdat { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime updatedat { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CourseContent> CourseContents { get; set; }
}
```

---

Now to read data, I used:

```
List<Student> studentlist = entities.Students.Include("StudentCourses").Where(s => s.status.Equals("active")).ToList<Student>();
```

Q.1. I want to add Course as well because I want to show the name of Course
Q.2. If I want to read data in view, how can I read course name?

For example:

```
foreach(var student in studentlist){
  student.first_name
  student.StudentCourses.fees       ( it is not working! )
  student.StudentCourses.Courses.course_name   ( it is not working! )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only including `StudentCourses`. Try this instead :

```
List<Student> studentlist = entities.Students.Include("StudentCourses")
                                             .Include("StudentCourses.Fees")
                                             .Include("StudentCourses.Course")
                                    .Where(s => s.status.Equals("active")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Reda for the reply, I tried but how should I read the data in my view. I've tried this:

    @student.StudentCourses.Course.course_name


But it is saying:

    'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<StudentManager.StudentCourse>' does not contain a definition for 'Course'

Comment: This is because `student.StudentCourses` in a collection. You have to iterate over it (with a `foreach` for example) to read the `Course` property for each `StudentCourse`.